# I want to leave some fields blank but getting error 400 Bad Request Is there a way for me to do that without getting the error

Tags: angular, laravel

Is there a way for me to do that without getting the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtKNi.png)
this is field but i fill in 2 field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGCf7.png)
Is it possible to fix this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFY4.png)
thanks

Comment: If the field is required it should be filled, if you want it to be empty or not present, just validate it to the expected data type without the require.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Looks like you've applied required in your validation.
Please remove the required attribute in validation and only add the expected data type without adding require.

Below attached codesnippet for Laravel validation:

```
`$this->validate($request,[
    'postTitle'=>'required|min:6|max:255',
    'imgDesc'=>'max:1000',
 ]);`
```

Thanks